# Windows10/MacOS(64-bit) on Rasp Pi 4b 4GB RAM

Tags: windows-iot, macos, 64-bit

I am looking to use Imaging Edge Desktop application on my Rasp Pi. Download here [1](https://imagingedge.sony.net/en/ie-desktop.html).

The application has Windows and Mac downloads but is not 32-bit compatible. Thus, I am looking to download 64-bit versions of Windows or MacOS on the Pi. Browsing the web I've found tutorials on how to

- (a) get 64-bit os(Raspbian, Ubuntu, etc)
- (b) get windows 10(doesn't say if 64-bit).

Note, either way the performance seems to dip substantially which may be an issue as I intend on running image processing python script(I'm not sure, I'm quite new to this type of thing).

If this is possible but would work much better on the 8GB RAM version of the Pi please specify.

*Thanks for any help you're willing to provide. Hopefully, my question is clear.*

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: long answer: just, no.

Comment: Confirmation of the answer from @kwasmich: **NO!**

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange community. I have taken some time to format your question a bit better - This really helps people read your question and I hope your answers in the future. Unfortunately your question is not really about Raspberry Pi. Please check my answer I expand a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 on ARM (and even MacOS) is imminent. We already have some solutions but they are not fully functional.

The problem you have is that software is compiled for x86 or AMD64 architectures only. Even if you got windows on ARM running on the Pi these won’t even install. Even if you try the architecture emulation it will be painfully slow.

Windows for ARM is already a thing and used with newer generations of ARM processors. The Pi4 is compatible. but as usual drivers are in the clutches of Broadcom which makes getting it fully stable a nightmare.

But some really awesome work has been done with Vulkan to DirectX11 emulation layer (its missing raytracing but the Pi doesn't support that.. but it DOES support Vulkan) So the stable version for Pi will land with full GPU support. Which the Pi has a decent GPU for the price

Knowing the hacker community there are people going to try and make MacOS ARM run on the Pi. I hope it does.. it will be amazing (for educational purposes only obviously - as running Mac on anything that does not have an Apple logo on it is breach of terms)

With the rise of ARM around global stake holders we will start to see more ARM build of such software which should make it possible to run natively on probably various ARM OS’s

Comment: Then you need the various third parties to start distributing versions of their software on Windows ARM.  Keeping in mind what happened the last time Microsoft tried to do this -- I think it is fair to say don't hold your breath.

Comment: I don't understand why you having a go at Microsoft? (P.S Please tell me what happened im not sure what you mean) If a company wants people to use their software they will compile it for that platform. Looking at that Imaging Edge software, they offer Windows and Mac binaries. Clearly no user base for Linux so why even bother. Apple has already begun its divorce with Intel and the next generations Macs are gonna be ARM based. Windows for ARM is ready ( Pi4? - We will see soon & its got Vulkan<>DirectX11) Something lacking in Raspbian.. since forever despite having the hardware since Pi 1

Comment: I wasn't really having a go at Microsoft.  By "what happened the last time" I just meant WRT Windows mobile.   I suppose the third party issue isn't that big an issue, the complications w/ compiling software have a lot more to do with the OS platform than the architecture, so if they distribute for Windows x86-64 they might as well do so for Windows ARM.  But in the context of this question, I still think the OP is best advised not to hold his/her breath.

Comment: You see Windows Mobile was a Ballmer disaster, just another one stacked on all his rubbish choices. But the Nadella paradigm is so much different. The clever thing is compiling for Mac Os / Linux on ARM will be really easy. Heck I can already compile application to native Linux with pure C# NetCore into a single `app.so` file and run it on x86/AMD64/ARM without SDK's across several platforms. The GUI is problematic but this is where Vulkan and and MAIU saves us. Any way regardless, the OP cant run Windows 32/64 on Pi yes. Was this asked before? I believe so.. worth linking to that question?

Comment: Thanks for the help. You asked  "I don't understand why you having a go at Microsoft", the reason being is that I have a Sony RX0M2 camera which I am trying to automate(as part of a research grant for my school). I'm exploring GUI(pyautogui) control of Sony's software in order to do this. I already have a Pi so I'm seeing if it can be used for these purposes. I already am using a servo(GPIO controlled) to turn the camera on.  I'm now looking into these x86-64 SBCs as well as PC sticks.

Comment: Hi Gumby - The meaning in "why you having a go at Microsoft" may have been lost in translation. I was asking why Goldilocks why he was criticizing MS. I understand why you are having a go (trying out) Microsoft but as explained it won't work as you expect. Good luck with your project I hope you find a suitable solution

Comment: Hello again, just in case you're curious I've decided to order the LattePanda Delta (https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1910.html). It comes with windows 10 64bit pre-activated and uses an intel x86 CPU. My research indicates this should work for my project. Thanks for the help and good wishes.

Comment: Please feel free to add that as an answer and accept it - or select an answer that is most appropriate and click the accept button.  That board is really cool.. but quite up there in price range compared to Raspberry Pi - Best of luck

Answer (score 3):

Raspberry Pi uses an ARM CPU.
Unless stated otherwise, macOS and Windows binaries nowdays are x86-64.
You would need to run an emulator for the x86-64 architecture (QEMU might be a viable choice), install Windows or what you need and even if you get it that far, the performance will be miserable.

You can get SBCs with x86 CPUs form intel or AMD. You can install Windows there and it will run so much better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control your DSLR camera from your Pi look to the gphoto2 software from [gphoto.org](http://gphoto.org/)

There is support for over 2000 cameras last time I looked so there is a chance your is in the list.

For Lightroom style catalogues and editing look to Darktable or digiKam and GIMP is the classic Photoshop replacement.